# Order by clause with multiple columns for different cases to sort

Tags: oracle, sorting, sql-order-by

[Student details table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7HOG.png)

--Please correct me if I am wrong or there is more optimize way to achieve it

--To have order by on multiple column you can use this approach but its not right because

--The first column in the decode function will treat the rest of the column as same data-type of its own

--So when its comes on date and marks its will sort as a var-char and not number, date respectively

--Same goes if the first column is number will treat rest of the column as number and through a error

--ORA-00932: inconsistent data-types: expected NUMBER got DATE

```
select 
   roll_number,
   admission_date,
   student_name,
   total_marks,
   progress
from 
   student_details
order by 
   case when upper(:dir) = 'ASC' then
      decode(:sort, 
         'student_name', student_name,
         'roll_number', roll_number, 
         'admission_date', admission_date, 
         'total_marks', total_marks,
         'progress', progress
      ) 
   end asc, 
   case when upper(:dir) = 'DESC' then
      decode(:sort, 
         'student_name', student_name,
         'roll_number', roll_number, 
         'admission_date', admission_date, 
         'total_marks', total_marks,
         'progress', progress
      ) 
   end desc;
```

-- TO achieve a proper multiple order by clause you need to use multiple cases for each column

-- or at-lest for each common set of data type columns

```
select 
   roll_number,
   admission_date,
   student_name,
   total_marks,
   progress
from 
   student_details
order by 
   case when upper(:dir) = 'ASC' and :sort = 'student_name' then 
      student_name 
   end asc, 
   case when upper(:dir) = 'ASC' and :sort = 'roll_number' then 
      roll_number 
   end asc,
   case when upper(:dir) = 'ASC' and :sort = 'admission_date' then 
      admission_date 
   end asc,
   case when upper(:dir) = 'ASC' and :sort = 'total_marks' then 
      total_marks 
   end asc,
   case when upper(:dir) = 'ASC' and :sort = 'progress' then 
      progress 
   end asc,
   case when upper(:dir) = 'DESC' and :sort = 'student_name' then 
      student_name 
   end desc,
   case when upper(:dir) = 'DESC' and :sort = 'roll_number' then 
      roll_number 
   end desc,
   case when upper(:dir) = 'DESC' and :sort = 'admission_date' then 
      admission_date 
   end desc,
   case when upper(:dir) = 'DESC' and :sort = 'total_marks' then 
      total_marks 
   end desc,
   case when upper(:dir) = 'DESC' and :sort = 'progress' then 
      progress 
   end desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your observations seems correct. There is one way which allows to shorten this syntax:

```
select *
  from (
    select * from students_details 
      order by case :sort when 'roll_number'    then roll_number end, 
               case :sort when 'admission_date' then admission_date end,
               case :sort when 'student_name'   then student_name end )
  order by rownum * decode(:dir, 'DESC', -1, 1)
```

Last line is important, it reverts ordering if you want it descending.

Source article: [CASE in ORDER BY statement](http://www.compoundtheory.com/case-in-order-by-statement/) (one of the comments).